# How to transform 'Cartesian gradient' taken from the formatted checkpoint file into the input orientation?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I would like to extract the energy gradient at a particular geometry with many digits from the formatted checkpoint file. However, Gaussian prints the gradient components related to the standard orientation. My question is how to convert this kind of gradient into its counterpart corresponding to the input orientation.

Comment: Do you have symmetry turned on? I think if you turn off symmetry Gaussian won't change the orientation of the molecule. Otherwise you need the matrix that transforms between the two orientations. By the way, you may want to check [Matter Modelling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com) as well.